# How to combine or simplify multiple 5-12V level shifters

Tags: voltage, converter, level-shifting

I've created the following model for a school project. This is the first time I'm attempting to read sensors or write alarms etc. using a microcontroller.

[image: Diagram]

How I can improve it? To me it seems likely that there's a way to combine these voltage converters.

As I was thinking, I could perhaps use one pin to control/read the sensor and another pin to 'multiplex' the other pin to the correct sensor after it's voltage has been shifted from 5V to 12V.

Would you recommend this approach? Or is there a much better or more common alternative?

**Note:**
All sensors have to be read, whereas the alarm has to be set. The temperature sensor is an analog sensor, all other sensors are digital.

Comment: Just use 5V sensors. It seems to me that 5V powered devices are all available for the types of applications in your diagram.

Comment: Are you talking about voltage (power) converters or only signal level converters?

What kind of signal do the sensors give? Logic or analog?

Comment: @Andyaka My teacher will only provide us with 12V sensors to force us to do some voltage shifting.

Comment: @Botnic I think I explained this at Note:, only the temperature sensor uses analog, all the other sensors are logical.

Comment: @user1534664 right sorry. Then I would do it like you showed. 12 to 5V conversion is easy, small and cheap. Easier than every shifting or multiplexing. Only the Alarm has to be done separately.

Comment: @Botnic I'm quite surprised about that to be honest. I'm glad I asked this then :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something like a [ULN2003A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf) or another variant of that family?
They are used extensively as interfaces between low level and high level devices.